# How to use sed to append a line in bash script with a variable

Tags: bash, sed

i am just trying to append a line from my bash script:

```
sed -i '$ a  TEXT'  "filename"
```

but when TEXT is a variable it does not work

```
sed -i '$ a  $VARIABLE'  "filename"
```

i have tested endless iterations with ',''," before/after $ and ${}, escape with \ etc., but i always get a literal $VARIABLE in my file

ps. please do not propose to use echo:)

Comment: `'$VARIRABLE'` does not gets expanded, use `"`, `sed -i '$ a   '"$VARIABLE" ...`

Comment: omg thank you. i always added an extra ' after the last double quote (and it didnt work)